# Nuget CA certificates error on a docker container of Asp.net core

Tags: ssl, docker, nuget, .net-core

I am trying to build a docker container of an asp.net code application and i get errors while trying to retrieve nuget packages

> docker build -t my:container .

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  9.58 MB
Step 1 : FROM microsoft/dotnet:latest
 ---> 3693707d4f7f
Step 2 : COPY . /app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 22a461236738
Step 3 : WORKDIR /app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 8bea2af489ad
Step 4 : RUN dotnet restore
 ---> Running in 5fbfe078c820
log  : Restoring packages for /app/project.json...
error: Unable to load the service index for source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json.
error:   An error occurred while sending the request.
error:   Peer certificate cannot be authenticated with given CA certificates
The command 'dotnet restore' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

The dockerfile i am using is a pretty standard one and based on microsoft/dotnet:latest container.

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:latest
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app

RUN ["dotnet", "restore"]
RUN ["dotnet", "build"]

EXPOSE 9881/tcp
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS http://*:9881

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "run"]
```

This used to work a while ago, something seems to have broken but i have no idea what would that be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that i was been using an experimental version 1.12.3 of docker.

Everything works great now that i installed the latest official version on windows (still 1.12.3 but not marked as experimental).